# Go HTTP ListenAndServe logging response

Tags: go

I was wondering if there is a way to log the responses when using ListenAndServe.

As far as I can tell, the handler doesn't have access to a "Response" object. Just a ResponseWriter, so I cannot call httputil.DumpResponse.

Comment: Do you need to log the entire response? Are just the headers OK?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http.ResponseWriter is an interface. You can use embedding to extend it for logging as follows.

```
package main
import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func sampleHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    response := []byte("Sample Response")
    w.Write(response)
}

type loggingResponseWriter struct {
    status int
    body   string
    http.ResponseWriter
}

func (w *loggingResponseWriter) WriteHeader(code int) {
    w.status = code
    w.ResponseWriter.WriteHeader(code)
}

func (w *loggingResponseWriter) Write(body []byte) (int, error) {
    w.body = string(body)
    return w.ResponseWriter.Write(body)
}

func responseLogger(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        loggingRW := &loggingResponseWriter{
            ResponseWriter: w,
        }
        h.ServeHTTP(loggingRW, r)
        log.Println("Status : ", loggingRW.status, "Response : ", loggingRW.body)
    })
}

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", responseLogger(http.HandlerFunc(sampleHandler)))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

You can wrap the handler functions that you want to log responses for with responseLogger.

Answer (score 1):

You can't because the response technically doesn't exist until you write it to the `ResponseWriter`.

But in the `response` is just the `header`, `body` and `response code` so in the handler function you can use method `Header()` on the `ResponseWriter` to get the header and then you can log the `response code` and the `body` before you write it to the `ResponseWriter`.

If you provide an example of what you are trying to do, I can elaborate on how to do it.

This is what I did to fix this for a small project:
I use this in all my handlers:

```
type transaction struct {
    res Response // Create this type also
    req Request // Create this type also
}

func NewTransaction(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) *transaction{}

Log := make(chan transaction, 100)
go func{
    // Read from channel and log the info however you want.
}()

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    tx := NewTransaction(w, req) // Struct with the request and response
    defer func() {
        Log <- tx
    }()

    /*
    Handle request here
    */

    // Update request and response
    Request.Body = body
}
```

And at the end of the handler function, after having served the requested data, I update the values for the request and the response.

And have a goroutine listening to the channel Log and doing all your logging.

Also you can write a wrapper function that serves the file and returns the response.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it doesn't scale. I have hundreds of handler functions, so I don't want to keep doing the same thing in each. I'd rather do it in a central place..

Comment: @SFO You are right. I added an example of how I have resolved this issue before. Is not as good as it could be but is a start.

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative, one can use fasthttp.

Comment: You should provide some code example, such as how a http handler would be written using `fasthttp` such that it would log the response, if you want the answer to be useful.